# Set an existing dropdown as multiselect dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic, html-select

I want so set an existing dropdown as multi-select dynamically

I have a Dropdown

```
<select id='ddSelect'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I want to set `#ddSelect` as multiselect.

Is there any option like `$('#ddSelect').attr('multiple').val('true')` or something?

Is that possible via jQuery or Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this by using:

```
$('#ddSelect').attr('multiple', true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [[DEMO]](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/h5PMS/).

```
<select id='ddSelect'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

$('#ddSelect').attr('multiple', true)
```